# Detecting newline when reading text file one character at a time

Tags: c#

Target file:

```
Hello
World
```

Code:

```
if (file != null)
{
    //Read file one character at a time
    StreamReader reader;
    reader = new StreamReader(file);
    do
    {
        int s = reader.Read();
        char sC = (char)s;
        if (sC.Equals(Environment.NewLine))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("+1");
        }
        Console.WriteLine((char)s);
    } while (!reader.EndOfStream);
    reader.Close();
    reader.Dispose();
}
```

Output:

```
H
e
l
l
o




W
o
r
l
d
```

So `(sC.Equals(Environment.NewLine))` obviously doesn't detect a platform independent newline when reading one char at a time.. how do I do this?

Comment: Any reason you can't `ReadLine` instead of `Read`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try this instead

```
if (sC.Equals('\n'))
```

If you are sure there will always be a `\r` after the `\n` then you can swallow it with another `reader.Read();` call. Example:

```
if (sC.Equals('\n')) {
   reader.Read()
   Console.WriteLine("+1");
}
```

Comment: This worked.. but it did leave a `\r` lingering.. I'm confused ;/

Answer (score 2):

That's because `Environment.NewLine` is a `String` consisting of `\r\n` (depends on your environment, on Windows platforms it's `\r\n`) - which are the Carrige Return and New Line characters - it's a pair that usually defines a *New line*.

So comparing a character (which can either be `\n` or `\r`) to `\r\n` will always yield `false`

Instead, as mentioned in @jurgen d's answer, try to compare to `\n`.

Comment: The start of your statement is not true for Unix/Linux environments (say running under Mono).

Answer (score 0):

`Environment.NewLine` is actually two characters: \r\n

Do you really need to read one char at a time? Wouldn't you prefer to use a [`StringReader`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stringreader.aspx) and use ReadLine() instead?

Answer (score 0):

easy way to remove \n\r

```
        String text = "test\n\r";
        if (text[text.Length - 1] == 10 && text[text.Length - 2] == 13)
            text= text.Substring(0, text.Length - 2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this-

```
if (sC.Equals('\r'))
```

As '\r' comes before '\n' in your case.