# How to read a Text File upto occurrence of a special character asterisk

Tags: c#, asp.net, filestream

Am trying to read a text file in asp.net where the file is not in a particular format, so i just wanted to read that file up to special characters(*) and skip the rest.

In general it is of the format

```
 00000 AFCX      TY88YYY
 12366 FTTT      TY88YYY
 ** File Description
 // This is so and so Description
 ** End of Description
 12345 TYUI      TY88YYY
 45677 RERY      TY88YYY
```

Comment: There are several ways to tackle this.  What have you tried?  What have you thought about trying?

Comment: Try to adapt the following to your needs: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10785960/detecting-newline-when-reading-text-file-one-character-at-a-time

Comment: I wanted to stop at the first * occarance

Comment: @Popeye i just wanted to skip the lines between * and continue with next lines

Answer (score 0):

```
    string file = "TextFile1.txt";
    List<string> lines = new List<string>();

    using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader(f))
    {
        string line;
        while ((line = r.ReadLine()) != null && !line.StartsWith("*"))
        {
            lines.Add(line);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This will give you a list of all the lines except those beginning with `*`:

```
string[] yourFileContents = File.ReadAllLines(filePath);
List<string> contentsWithoutAsterix = 
    yourFileContents.Where(line => line.First() != '*').ToList();
```

**PS (edit):**

If you just want lines *until the first* occurence of `*`, do this instead:

```
List<string> contentsWithoutAsterix =
         yourFileContents.TakeWhile(line => line.First() != '*').ToList();
```